# RESTful Response when the POST request results in the creation of different kind of resources?

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I have been working on designing an API that lets client create a product (think of product as something like website domain, something that comes into existence when client makes order for it to the service). Correspondingly with every purchase results in creation of the order object. Which means creation of two resources via a single POST request.

So afaik, the RFC standards recommends sending `201` on resource creation with URI for the resource in the `Location` header. But in the above scenario, we are creating two resources, domains and orders and I would want response to contain information related to both the resources.

Response would look something similar to this

```
POST /domains/
Request 
 body: {"domain_name": "awesome.com"},

Response
 Body: {"order_id": "1234"}
 Headers: 
   Location: http://example.com/awesome.com
```

But does not look very RESTful. I was wondering if there was a RESTful way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think this is not RESTful?

Comment: Wouldn't modeling it as `POST /orders/domains` be better?

Comment: @Andy, imo the parent resource being created is `domain`  and `POST /orders/domains` makes it seem like `domain` somehow come under the `order` resource which does not feel right.  Plus the issue of how do I indicate creation of both the resources still remains unsolved with the above endpoint.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, i cant  find specification for similar situation on RFC and seems like a very common case so not very sure if this approcah is RESTful. Moreover the two approaches that I have come across online are mostly either sending `Location` header  or just sending the instance of the complete resource in the response body. So the above approach does not seem very clear and standardised to me and would rather want to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

REST itself is separate from the HTTP protocol.

A Rest based response should represent the current state of the conversation, or at least the delta of change in the state. This would generally be a description of anything new, and information about things they can now do. Exactly like a web page, which describes information (the content) and has links/forms representing actions the user can take.

---

The fact that HTTP also suggests that you return the new resource location in a header field `location` is simply a standardisation, in this case to direct the browser to that content as an automated redirect. So pick the resource that feels best to place here.

HTTP also has a `Content-Location` which is meant to hold the location of a returned resource.

Putting these two together the software can return `location` with a url that would naturally redirect to, say the newly created domain. Which works for dumb browsers/agents they will now go to the domain. Smarter agents though can take advantage of the fact that the body contains a resource (the `order`) and the `Content-Location` of that order.

---

However this is missing the point. This is a Representational State Transfer, so nail down the representation. What are you being given and, how are you responding?

Sounds like the user is giving you the domain name. Presumably success means that this is now a thing. It is indeed a resource, but do you need to repeat to the user what they just said?

```
request> mydomain.com
response> http://mydomain.com
```

Sure it is legitimate, but what is being achieved here?

What else is happening? The server is making an `Order` resource. Does the user know about this? Probably not, or at least they don't know where it is.

```
request> mydomain.com
response> http://example.com/order/abcdef1234567890/
```

And the order doubtlessly also includes a link to the domain, should they have forgotten what they were requesting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the above response. I wanted to return domain related information since after the creation of `domain` resource there are a bunch of field that `client` might want to have a look at (`expires_at`, `terminates_at`, `status` etc).  The `order` resource wont contain these fields.

Comment: @AdityaKumarGupta, could one of the domain fields be the `creation_order` with a link to the `order` resource? Or you could even return the `order` resource as a sub-resource (with optionally a link to where you can retrieve just the `order` resource).